Extended Processing Time - Logging In
We are experiencing slow processing times when initiating a login from our mobile app using the Salesforce SDK, and we are seeking guidance on how to improve or troubleshoot this process. Here’s an outline of our current login flow:

Initiate Login via SDK: The login process is initiated through the Salesforce SDK in our mobile app.
OAuth Authentication: Upon receiving a success callback from the SDK, we call the oauth.getAuthCredentials method to obtain an access token.
Member Info API Call: After obtaining the access token, we call the Member Info API to retrieve user details such as email, loyalty ID, etc.
User Login: If we successfully receive user information from the API, we proceed to log in the user.

The main issue is the delay between the initiation of the login and the successful retrieval of user information, which is impacting the overall user experience. We have already reviewed network conditions, SDK configurations, and API performance, but the login process remains slow.
Are there any specific optimizations or settings within Salesforce SDK, OAuth authentication, or API calls that could help reduce the processing time? Additionally, any best practices or insights into streamlining this type of login flow would be highly appreciated.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
